# Categories widget in sidebar

Tags: category, magento-1, widget, sidebar

I created a widget and assigned the following values to it:

- Type: Catalog Category Link
- Design Package/Theme: rwd / default
- Widget Instance Title: Categories
- Sort Order: 1

Now I want it displayed in the sidebar below the default poll.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best call is to create a static block in `CMS > Static Blocks`, insert the widget within it, and then adjust your theme `local.xml` to insert the static block there:

```
<catalog_category_default>

     <reference name="left">
          <block type="cms/block" name="your_block_name" after="the_poll_identifier">
              <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>your_block_id</block_id></action>
          </block>
     </reference>       

</catalog_category_default>
```

Comment: So there is no native way to add stuff to the sidebar?  By the way, these newly created categories are not showing up anywhere (header, etc).  What is the default place for them?